# Compile A MSVC++2010 Project So It Can Run On Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cross-platform

I have a MSVC++ 2010 project. All the libraries it's using are cross platform (SDL, OpenGL and FLTK).

Obviously, all I have to do right now is press the debug button and it will compile a nice old .exe for me which can now run on Windows, as long as the DLL files are with it.

I had thought before that if you use cross platform libraries, then the generated .exe would run fine on Ubuntu too. I recently found out that this is not possible, and that the program must be compiled in a special way to run on a certain platform.

Is it possible to compile my project in this magical way with MSVC++ 2010 so that it can run on a Ubuntu computer? If so, then could you please answer my question with some clear steps as to what I should do to compile it this way, keeping in mind I'm new to how all this cross platform stuff works?

EDIT:

If I cannot compile a MSVC++ 2010 project for Ubuntu, is there an IDE I could use that could compile the project for both Windows and Ubuntu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use QT. http://qt.digia.com/ 
It's probably the best cross platform IDE that can let you compile for Windows, Mac and Linux(ubuntu) systems.

Comment: Alright, im looking at it and yeah, it seems like it will do the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not possible. While the binary code corresponding to the program can be portable, that's not enough. Executable formats on various file systems are different and not compatible. The executable format is essentially a packaging of the binary data and wrapping it with a header that the target file system understands. In order to produce executables for Ubuntu, the linker must support it. MSVC++ doesn't support Linux formats.

Comment: Is there another IDE that I could use to compile it for both Windows and Ubuntu?

Comment: See @KirillIvlev suggestion